# handling ManagementScope.timeout in c#

Tags: c#, wmi

The following code is used for connecting to a remote (WMI) Object using system.management.ManagementScope (C#).

```
mgmtScope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + strHostAddress + "\\" + WMIConnection.dictWMINamespace[nameSpace] + "", connOptions); 
string WMITimeOut = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WMIConnectionTimeout"];
TimeSpan wmiTimeOutts;
int value;
if (int.TryParse(WMITimeOut, out value))
{
    wmiTimeOutts = new TimeSpan(0, 0, value);
}
else
{
    wmiTimeOutts = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60);
}

mgmtScope.Options.Timeout = wmiTimeOutts;
mgmtScope.Connect();
```

Recently I have added code for timeout. Now I want to do some actions when a request timeout occurs.

Not sure how to find out whether the request has been  timed out or not. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Sebastian

Answer (score 1):

The Timeout property is intended for 'semi-synchronous' enumeration of results. It will not detect a connection timeout.

See
[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.enumerationoptions.returnimmediately.aspx) for more information